# Arial font is not produced with lithuanian language

Tags: fonts, languages

How can I get Arial font with my native language?

My unsuccessful try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

    Hello, World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage{tgheros}` instead of `helvet`: the Helvetica font does not come with L7x encoded fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lithuanian module for `babel` requires fonts in the L7x encodings. Not all of the usually available fonts have these, in particular the Helvetica clone provided by `\usepackage{helvet}`.

However there's TeX Gyre Heros (another Helvetica clone) that has the required fonts, so

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
```

should solve your problem. It also has the `scale` option, so that you can fine tune the appearance with something like

```
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgheros}
```

(actually 0.95 is the default).